# In how many orders can perfumes and colognes be sprayed?

Tags: combinatorics

A perfume tester is testing perfumes in a store and needs to spray 4 perfumes and 3 colognes.

a) In how many orders can they be sprayed, only taking the type into account? (4 perfumes are IDENTICAL, and 3 Colognes are IDENTICAL)

b) If we must begin and end with a perfume how many orders can they be sprayed?

I attempted using partitions method to solve it like * P * P * P * P * with 5 positions to "place" the C, but I think this is wrong. Could anyone help?

Comment: Have you heard of binomial coefficients?  Have you seen some of the interpretations that can be applied to the number $\binom{n}{k}$, specifically as it relates to bitstrings of length $n$?  Do you see why the problem in a) can be described as counting the number of bit strings of length seven with four 1's and three 0's?

Comment: I can see that, I'm not sure how to implement that in this scenario though.

Answer (score 2):

Visualize placing the perfumes and colognes in a sequence, and spraying them in that sequence.

Part (i): Out of 7 possible places, we must choose 4 for the perfumes. Thus, the answer is:

$\binom{7}{4} = \boxed{35}$

Part (ii): Since both end places must be taken up by perfumes, we eliminate them from the count.  Now, we need to choose 2 places out of the center 5 to put the remaining perfumes. Thus, the answer is:

$\binom{5}{2} = \boxed{10}$

Comment: Thank you! Very clear explanation